# Access CKAN Source Files Via Shared Files In Vagrant

Tags: vagrant, ckan

#### Background Info

I've installed CKAN into a Vagrant environment and I want to be able to view and edit both the config files (`etc/ckan`) and source files (`/usr/lib/ckan`) in my a text editor on my local machine (not in Vim over ssh). Here is my folder structure:

- `CKAN/`

  - `VagrantFile`
  - `ckan-config/`
  - `ckan-source/`

The following two lines in my `VagrantFile` allow me to view the `ckan-config` and `ckan-source` folders in my local desktop:

```
config.vm.synced_folder "ckan-config/", "/etc/ckan"
config.vm.synced_folder "ckan-source/", "/usr/lib/ckan"
```

#### Here's my problem

The first line from above syncs the `ckan-config` folder (contains things like `datapush_settings.py`, and `default/development.ini`) and that works fine. However, if I leave the second line uncommented then CKAN doesn't work. I get a **500 Internal Server Error**.

I've tried commenting out the second line, starting the Vagrant box, uncommenting it, and then running `vagrant reload` but CKAN still won't boot. I still get the same **500 Internal Server Error**.

#### How I created the local folders in the first place

- Created a working CKAN environment
- `vagrant ssh`ed into it
- created a new git repository and added `/etc/ckan` into it
- created another new git repository and added `/usr/lib/ckan` into it
- exited from ssh
- went to the same directory the `VagrantFile` is in
- git cloned both repositories
- added the two lines (above) into the `VagrantFile`
- ran `vagrant reload`

Sorry for the long post. Just want to make everything clear from the get go. Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: What does the ckan log say the problem is?

Comment: @DRead Where is the CKAN log? I can't find any reference to it in the docs. `/var/log/apache2/ckan_default.error.log` returns a huge list of errors. The last line reads: `[Mon Mar 27 14:20:20.193664 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 1536:tid 140204656879360] [remote 127.0.0.1:65016] DistributionNotFound: The 'ckan' distribution was not found and is required by the application`

Comment: Yeah, not easy to find, but it is in the docs under "Log files" on this page http://docs.ckan.org/en/latest/maintaining/installing/deployment.html#troubleshooting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a good way to work with Vagrant and ckan. I suggest you re-create these two directories from scratch:

1. Add those two lines to your Vagrantfile
2. `vagrant reload`
3. `vagrant ssh`
4. Rerun three [CKAN install steps](http://docs.ckan.org/en/latest/maintaining/installing/install-from-source.html): "2. Install CKAN into a Python virtual environment" "4. Create a CKAN config file" "8. Link to who.ini"

NB I did this and ran into an issue with Beaker, which is detailed here with a workaround: https://github.com/ckan/ckan/issues/3512

By copying the source directory (via git), you've probably messed up some subtlety of the install or virtualenv - e.g. hidden files, symlinks etc. - and you've ended up with CKAN not installed in the virtualenv, according to that error message. It's best to add these lines to your Vagrantfile first, rather than after your install.

Comment: I've fleshed out this general approach and provided it as a wiki page: https://github.com/ckan/ckan/wiki/How-to-Install-CKAN-2.6.2-on-Vagrant

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure `root` user owns your folder, as you synced them from your local host, the default owner will be vagrant

change your settings with

```
config.vm.synced_folder "ckan-config/", "/etc/ckan", owner: "root", group: "root"
config.vm.synced_folder "ckan-source/", "/usr/lib/ckan", owner: "root", group: "root"
```

It might be that you need to check permissions as well, for the `/usr/lib/ckan` folder you might need to add `mount_options: ["dmode:775" ,"fmode=664"]`